# getJSON allways goes to fail, MVC .NET

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get a JSON from my controller in ASP.Net MVC. The `$.getJSON` always goes to the `fail` function. My controller is working right. The object arrives with the correct data, and builds the JSON ok, with no incorrect data.

```
public JsonResult Rentabilidad(ObtenerRentabilidadViewModel data)
{
    var JsonChart = Json(RentabilidadManager.Rentabilidad(data.DTInicio, data.DTFinal), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return JsonChart;
}
```

After the request to my controller the JSON jumps directly to the `fail` part.

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("Rentabilidad")', { 
    Inicio: fechaInicio, 
    Final: fechaFinal 
}, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function (jq,msg,error) {
    console.log(jq);
    console.log(msg);
    console.log(error);

    $("#chartdiv").html('<div class="alert alert-danger col-md-12" id="alert">Error! Vuelva a intentarlo. </div>');
    Desvanecer3segundos("#alert");
});
```

And the console shows:

```
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "[{"Ingresos":0,"Egresos":1334,"Proyecto":"proy1","…2,"Rentabilidad":Infinity,"BulletSize":Infinity}]", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
Index:114 parsererror
Index:115 SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 172(…)
```

Thanks!

Comment: The `fail` is hit if the request responds with anything other than a `2xx` HttpStatusCode, which implies your Action has an error, or the response is not formatted correctly, which is unlikely in this case. Check the console for the exact error being generated

Comment: If you add some arguments to the `fail(jqXHR, errText, error)` you'll probably see why

Comment: I'll post what I'm getting

Comment: It is returning a 200 response. Are you sure it is going to fail part ?

Comment: 100% cause it's showing the div error

Comment: It's parsing error `"…2,"` not proper json

Comment: Use `console.log(jq.responseText)` and paste that. The console does not show the entirety of the responseText value, which is causing the `…2,` others have pointed out. That's not likely what the error is about however, since that's not a position 172 of the responseText.

Answer (score 0):

You have some invalid JSON getting parsed:

"Proyecto":"proy1","…2,"Rentabilidad"

Notice that the `...2` has a double quote before it, but no double quote after it.  Also, it doesn't have a property name affiliated with it.

Comment: Debug your controller and see what your object is prior to even getting a response to the client

Answer (score 0):

Some values where set to "Inifint" and "NaN".

Thank you everybody!